# I run live-server in terminal, how do I write more commands after this...?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, liveserver

I run live-server in the terminal on VS Code, afterwards I try to write a new command in the terminal but I don't get any response, what command do I need to write to continue to use the terminal?

I've tried writing cd ../

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the shell job is running in the foreground. Either run the shell job in the background (how to do this varies from shell to shell), or just create a new integrated terminal session (see the "+" button in the Terminal Panel of VS Code).

Answer (score 0):

When a server is started there is no solution solution to use the same terminal but you can run another terminal and use it